# Logarithmic Recursive function

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

Is it possible to solve the following recursive relation?

$f(n) = 
\begin{cases}
f(\frac{n}{\log{n}}) + 1 \quad n\geq 3
\\ 1 \qquad \qquad \quad \ \    n< 3
\end{cases}$

I tried to solve it by assuming $n = e^{m}$, but it didn't work.

Comment: How do you define $f(1)$ ? There is a problem with $n=2$ as $\log 2<1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc, I changed the base case

Comment: There is a unique function on $\Bbb R$ satisfying this recursion, but it's not going to have a nice form. Even the interval on which $f(n)=2$ involves a non-elementary function (it involves the Lambert $W$-function), and it will keep getting worse as we go through larger $n$.

Comment: $f(x)$ basically counts the number of applications of $\frac{x}{\log x}$ it takes on $x$ to get below $3$, plus one.